# Serialization of MVC model with partial class won't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've passed all day long with a serialization problem with nested properties (an array in particular) and MVC.
I've created a simple code to show you a simplification. I premit I've just googled and tried even to put the `Items[0].Id` as the name of the html helper.

By the way here-s the code *maybe you can provide me a working and clean solution.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Salva", "Home", new AjaxOptions(){ HttpMethod = "POST"}))
{
<div class="row">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_Item", Model.Items[i])
    }
</div>
<input value="click" type="submit"/>
}
```

The models

```
namespace WebApplication2.Models
{
public class SomeClass
{
    public Internal[] Items { get; set; }
}

public class Internal
{
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

}

and here's the controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SomeClass();

        var lst = new List<Internal>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(new Internal{Id = i});
        }
        model.Items = lst.ToArray();
        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Salva(SomeClass model)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
}
```

and here's _Item.cshtml

```
    @model namespace.Internal

     Html.TextFor(m=>m.Date)
```

I hoped that creating a simple priject would clean my doubt and see where I was doing wrong in the real project but with no luck... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: please post _Item cshtml

Comment: edited via mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change mapping between `model` and `view`.

To mapping your input name must have follow name `someClass.Items[" + ViewBag.Index + "].Date`

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Salva(SomeClass someClass)
        {
            return Json(true);
        }
```

In _Item.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication1.Controllers.Internal

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date,  htmlAttributes : new  { Name = "someClass.Items[" + ViewBag.Index + "].Date" })
```

In Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Salva", "Users", new AjaxOptions(){ HttpMethod = "POST"}))
{
    <div class="row">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Length; i++)
        {
            ViewBag.Index = i;
            @Html.Partial("_Item", Model.Items[i])
        }
    </div>
    <input value="click" type="submit"/>
}
```